# How B+tree is serialized into disk in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, b-tree

I know how B+tree works in memory but I'm confused how it is used by database like MySQL.

Without any optimization, tree nodes(leaf or non-leaf) should be save to disk if any data is updated/inserted and should be loaded from disk if someone search.

How B+tree nodes are serialized into one file on disk ? Random-access in disk seems inevitable.

Comment: The B+Tree nodes (both leaf and non-leaf, both data and index) are 16KB "blocks" that are cached in the buffer_pool in roughly a least-recently-used mode.  All SQL activity happens in the buffer_pool.

Comment: @RickJames Are the non-LRU "blocks" saved into disk file ? I'm curious about how they are serialized and deserialized.

Comment: A "block" is written as-is to disk (in the "tablespace" where it is assigned).  (OK, there is a checksum put somewhere in the block.)  (And if you have `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`, a lot of other work goes on.)  The block is assigned a fixed location in the tablespace.  Are those points what you mean by "serialized"?

Comment: Yes, there are other "blocks" in the buffer_pool.  For one, see "change buffering" for performing "delayed-writes" to non-unique indexes.  In this case, they are not written to disk; rather, `INDEX` blocks are read, updated, and rewritten.  Again, these may be done in an LRU order.

Comment: What do you mean by "serialized"?  (I may not be asking the question you wanted to ask.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, random access happens continually in InnoDB. The B+Tree data structure for indexes is written to many pages in a tablespace, not necessarily consecutive pages. Each page has links to the next page(s), which may be anywhere in the tablespace.

This is mitigated by loading pages into RAM, into the innodb buffer pool, where random access does not incur overhead.

If you're interested in details about how InnoDB stores indexes on pages, I suggest studying Jeremy Cole's series of blog posts: https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/